# Angular cannot call method from service with observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs-observables

I have a service with this code:

```
cars() {
    return 'something here';
}
```

Then from the component I want to get the data with an observable so I'm doing this:

```
getcars() {
    this.dataService.cars().subscribe((result) => {
      console.log(result);
  });
}
```

I cannot do this as I'm getting:

```
Error: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What will 'something here' be..? Just a string? Or a http call to an external service?

Comment: `subscribe` keyword is used to attach to a RxJS [observable](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable) and listen to it's notifications. It does not exist on any other types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'string'. Is telling you that you are trying to call the `subscribe()` function on a string. Strings aren't an Observable that you can subscribe to. You should either not use subscribe or return an observable from the service.

To create an observable from a value, you can use `of`.

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';

cars() {
  return of('something here');
}
```